# ControllerContext is null and BaseController.OnActionExecuting() not called when using Html.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, action-filter

We use a `BaseController` to cache basic authentication information before every action executes:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected bool IsLoggedIn { get; set; }
    protected string Username { get; set; }
    ...

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var identity = base.User.Identity;
        this.IsLoggedIn = identity.IsAuthenticated;
        this.Username = identity.Name;

        ...
    }
}
```

And our child controller has a actions for the main page (Index) and a partial view (GetNavigation):

```
[Authorize]
public partial class CollaborationController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual ViewResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = this.MakeViewModel<FullPageViewModel>();
        return this.View(MVC.Collaboration.Views.Index, viewModel);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual PartialViewResult GetNavigation()
    {
        var viewModel = NavigationViewModel.Make(this.User);
        return this.PartialView(MVC.Collaboration.Views.Navigation, viewModel);
    }
}
```

And the partial view is rendered directly with `Html.Action()`:

```
@Html.Action(MVC.Collaboration.GetNavigation())
```

Seems like it should work, but `BaseController.OnActionExecuting` does not get called.  And I can't even call it directly because `this.ControllerContext` and `base.User` are both `null`.  I also tried subclassing `ActionFilterAttribute`, but its OnActionExecuting method doesn't get called, either.

Comment: Should probably also be noted that we're using MVCContrib

Comment: Did you update the T4MVC templates?

Comment: Yes, those are up to date.  It turns out that the MVCContrib html helper is the culprit.  It does call the action but with null controller context.  I switched to `@Html.Action("GetNavigation", "Collaboration")` and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but here is how I handle this. In my child controller I create the OnActionExecuting method and call the base controller from there.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
     base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least sort-of answered my own question:

Substituting

```
@Html.Action("GetNavigation", "Collaboration")
```

for

```
@Html.Action(MVC.Collaboration.GetNavigation())
```

fixes it.  MVCContrib's syntax seems to be the culprit, anyone know why?  Even better, anyone know a work-around that lets me avoid those nasty, non-refactoring-safe, magic strings?